# Meaning or functionality of this const variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Please, if anyone out there can, explain to me or tell me what the line of code *const [anyVariable]* really means here:

```
router.put('/:id', withAuth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const [anyVariable] = await BlogPost.update(req.body, {
        where: {
        id: req.params.id,
        },
});
```

Thank you!
--Willie

Comment: this is array destructuring assignment in JS. Suppose you have array `[1, 2]`.
`const [a] = [1, 2];` will assign `variable a` with `value 1`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called array `destructuring assignment` in JS. It `unpack values` from arrays, or properties from objects, into `individual variables`.

```js
const [num1, num2] = [11, 22, 33];
console.log(num1, num2);
```